# In ASP.Net Zero, Why I am not getting records when I try to execute an API using Angular UI but when I use swagger It returns the expected value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

ScreenCast Video Screen Capture: https://www.screencast.com/t/iwbNw1qwzGa

When you see the screen capture. It will show the first part where I demonstrate the calling of API using the Angular UI and the second part is where I use Swagger UI to call the API. You can see there that the first part displays calls the API and returns 0 records on the response when executing the GetAll() function of the default method of the ASP.Net Zero. But in the second part where it executes the API via swagger it returns the expected value from the DB. Please help on this issue. Thanks in advance.

See details of my code:

Component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.loadGroupHeaderCombo();
}
​
loadGroupHeaderCombo()
{
    this._groupHeadersService.getAllGroupHeaderCombo()
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.primengTableHelper.hideLoadingIndicator()))
    .subscribe(result =>{
        this.groupHeaderNamesSelectItems = _.map(result.groupHeaderNames, function(groupHeader) {
            return {
                label: groupHeader.displayText, value: groupHeader.value
            };
        });

        return result;
    });
}
```

Service-proxies

```
getAllGroupHeaderCombo(): Observable<GetGroupHeaderOutput> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/GroupHeaders/GetAllGroupHeaderCombo";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");
    let options_ : any = {
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };
    return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
        return this.processGetAllGroupHeaderCombo(response_);
    })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            try {
                return this.processGetAllGroupHeaderCombo(<any>response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<GetGroupHeaderOutput>><any>_observableThrow(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<GetGroupHeaderOutput>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
    }));
}
protected processGetAllGroupHeaderCombo(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<GetGroupHeaderOutput> {
    const status = response.status;
    const responseBlob = 
        response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body : 
        (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;
    let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
    if (status === 200) {
        return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
        let result200: any = null;
        let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
        result200 = GetGroupHeaderOutput.fromJS(resultData200);
        return _observableOf(result200);
        }));
    } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
        return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
        return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
        }));
    }
    return _observableOf<GetGroupHeaderOutput>(<any>null);
}
```

API Function

```
  public async Task<GetGroupHeaderOutput> GetAllGroupHeaderCombo()
  {
        var output = new GetGroupHeaderOutput();
        //Issue is ocurring here
        var x = _groupHeaderRepository.GetAll();
        //GroupHeader
        output.GroupHeaderNames =  _groupHeaderRepository
                                    .GetAll()
                                    .Select(s => new ComboboxItemDto
                                    {
                                        DisplayText = s.GroupTitle,
                                        IsSelected = false
                                    })
                                    .ToList();
   }
```

Comment: What is ASP.Net Zero?

Comment: FlashPlayer is required for the screencast you attached (which a lot of developers would not want to install anymore on their machine). How about you upload it to a video sharing site instead? To go back to your question, are you not running into CORS (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj25Nz6g_7lAhViIjQIHY2QA4gQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Faspnet%2Fweb-api%2Foverview%2Fsecurity%2Fenabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api&usg=AOvVaw3eTllF3lg8fPFIPI537ceE) issue?

Comment: @Amy ASP.Net Zero is a new framework to startup your project. This Framework I'm using is bundled with ASP.Net Core + Angular 8 UI

Comment: @Angelo I think you can enable the flash in chrome without installing anything on your local PC.

Comment: @RamilCastillo - I am not using Chrome, but rather FF. Also, CORS link should be for the .net Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: @Angelo OK Angelo I'll try to upload it and reshare it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

what i notice are 1.from your API your change list async

2.clean your service.proxy file and run 'refresh.bat' in your nswag file to generate new proxies.

Comment: toListAsycn instead of toList. clean service proxy file then debug your api from swagger